# Dolby Digital Live (DDL) on Asus Rampage II Gene (Creative X-Fi Extreme)

Tags: windows-7, audio, spdif, dolbydigital

I have an Asus Rampage II Gene motherboard which has X-Fi extreme built in. I can get it to work with Windows 7 ok using the Creative drivers, however when I try and install the DDL/DTS add on pack from Creative I get the error message:

*"There are no supported audio device available. You need to close the application. Click OK to close the application now"*

I don't understand it because I have the Creative software installed ok and supporting the sound without any problems. In Device manager the audio device comes up as 'High definition audio device' and uses driver: 6.1.7600.16385 from Microsoft.

I tried using the Creative drivers which show up as 'soundmax HD audio' however these do not allow any of the Creative products to run properly.

Please can anyone offer any help? Or even just confirm that DDL can work with my onboard sound?

---

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit
- 6GB DDR3
- XFX GS8800 384mb
- Asus Rampage II Gene
- Intel i7 920 (2.66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only work around that I could use for this was to go back to basics and use the analog outputs aswell as the optical out on my motherboard and connect them both to my av receiver.

I then used a program called vista audio changer which will automatically switch between sound outputs for you when it sees specific processes running. The program also works in windows 7, I haven't tried it in XP.

**[Vista Audio changer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vachanger/)**

(please note: these screenshots aren't of my setup)

[image]

So I setup the app to monitor for hl2.exe and change to 'speakers' whenever I play team fortress 2, and when I am finished it automatically switches back to the optical output. You can also change outputs manually via a system tray icon:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try these drivers from the famous Daniel_K: http://forums.creative.com/t5/Sound-Blaster/SB-P17X-Series-Support-Pack-2-0-07-31-2009-AudigySE-Value-LS/td-p/533291

If these don't install, then you don't have a real X-Fi Extreme Audio. You probably have "soundmax HD audio" which is a very low-end sound chipset.

Comment: I'll give them a bash (although I did already try a driver from daniel_k with no luck). My motherboard spec says:

SupremeFX X-Fi onboard

Listen with Absolute HD
SupremeFX X-Fi delivers an excellent high definition audio experience to the gamers of ROG. The SupremeFX X-Fi features unique audio innovations for gamers to spot enemes in 3D environment during game play. SupremeFX X-Fi also provides gamers a special tool to emphasize human voices in games to help make dialogues clearer and more audible.

Comment: I just checked out the specs of your motherboard. The exact name of the audio chipset is "SupremeFX X-Fi". So it's not X-Fi Extreme Audio and it's probably not from Creative.

Comment: When trying to install the daniel_k driver you sent me the link for, I get:

---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Setup is unable to detect a supported product on your system. Please ensure that your product is properly installed before running this Setup program.

Setup will exit.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: The chip is creative - the ASUS driver disk comes with creative drivers and software for the audio. Only problem is they don't include DDL!